# ARMv7( ResPi) Code- a program in ARMv7( ResPi) to Read 10 values from keyboard, store them in memory as array

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, armv7

I have this ARMv& code that should be doing this: a program in ARMv7( RasPi) to Read 10 values from keyboard, store them in memory as array. Ask user which number to display, and print that number only.

´Use an external C scanf to input

,but I am getting this error "Illegal instruction", could you help me with narrowing down the issue? I am running the code in ResPi 3 Model B+ (Linux).

Thanks,

```
.LC0:

.ascii "Please enter 10 numbers randomly\000"     @string declared for input

.LC1:

.ascii "%d\000"                                   @format specifier for scanf

.LC2:

.ascii "\012Which number do you want to see?\000"   @string for input

.LC3:

.ascii "It is %d\000"                                  @string for output

.text
.globl   main
.extern printf


main:                                                  @main program started

push {fp, lr}                                         @load fp and lr to stack

add fp, sp, #4                                      @Intialize file pointer

sub sp, sp, #48                                 @intialize stack pointer

ldr r0, .L10                                     @load string 1 from .L10

bl printf                                       @jump to label printf

mov r3, #0                                  @Assign i=0 and store value in register r3

str r3, [fp, #-8]                           @Set value as arr[i]

b .L2                                         @jump to L2

.L3:                                     @L3 block started

sub r2, fp, #48                        @subtract 48 from file pointer

ldr r3, [fp, #-8]                      @load value to r3 register

lsl r3, r3, #2                     @perform logical shift left for index change

add r3, r2, r3                 @Add content of r2 and r3 register

mov r1, r3                         @Move content of r3 register to r1

ldr r0, .L10+4                       @load content from L10 to ro register

bl __isoc99_scanf                @jump to scanf for input

ldr r3, [fp, #-8]                  @load value to r3 register

add r3, r3, #1                    @Increment i by 1

str r3, [fp, #-8]                 @Save the value of r3 to [fp, #-8]

.L2:                                          @L2 block

ldr r3, [fp, #-8]                           @load value to r3

cmp r3, #9                               @compare value of i to 9

ble .L3                                     @if less than 9 then jump L3

.L6:                                  @L6 block

ldr r0, .L10+8                      @load value to register r0

bl printf                                 @jump to printf

sub r3, fp, #52                     @Move to next index

mov r1, r3                           @Move content r3 to r1

ldr r0, .L10+4                     @load value to register r0

bl __isoc99_scanf               @jump to scanf function

ldr r3, [fp, #-52]               @load value to r3 register

cmp r3, #0                         @compare value of num to 0

blt .L9                                @if less than 0 then jump to L3 block

ldr r3, [fp, #-52]              @load value to r3 register

lsl r3, r3, #2                     @Shift to next index

sub r2, fp, #4                   @subtract from file pointer and result in r2 register

add r3, r2, r3                    @Add value of r2 and r3 register

ldr r3, [r3, #-44]            @load value to r3 register

mov r1, r3                        @move content of r3 register to r1

ldr r0, .L10+12                 @load value to ro register

bl printf                           @jump to printf statement

b .L6                              @branch to L6 block

.L9:                               @L9 block

nop                                    @do nothing

mov r3, #0                     @Assign r3=0

mov r0, r3                       @Move content of r3 to r0 register

sub sp, fp, #4                  

pop {fp, lr}                 @deintialize stack

bx lr                             @return

.L10:

.data

.word .LC0                         @first string

.word .LC1                         @second string

.word .LC2                         @third string

.word .LC3                         @fourth string
```

Comment: "Illegal instruction" at compile time or at run time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARM assembly, but I believe you have to use a call instruction to execute printf, not a conditional jump.

Comment: strictly speaking you could execute `printf` with jump, only problem you could not return back from that `printf` after :(

Comment: PMF, yes at compile time , Thanks.

Comment: @ 
user3124812 , I agree, but not sure why I could not return, I hope some ARM expert will shed some light on this. Thank you!

Comment: @PMF `bl` is essentially a call on the ARMv7.  The mnemonic is "Branch with Link" and It places the required return address in `r14` (the 'link register').

Comment: @Leolee More information would be good.  Which toolchain are you using?  Assembly language syntaxes differ widely even on a single platform.  What *exactly* is the error message that you're getting, and to which line does it refer?

Comment: @cooperised Thanks for the explanation. `bl` sounded like "branch if less" to me.

Comment: @cooperised I am running the code on Win10 using CMD on RasPi remote server, the error is Illegal instruction line 132.

Comment: Update: now I am getting this error:      as -o HW3.o HW3.s
raspberrypi:~$ gcc -o HW3 HW3.o
raspberrypi:~$ ./HW3 ; echo $?
Segmentation fault
139

Comment: @Leolee Still not enough information, I'm afraid.  Win10 and CMD are irrelevant, it's the compiler that's important.  I see from your other comment that it's GCC, but version would help.  Also we have no idea what line 132 is...